# How do I compare an element on a site with a given variable and use that in an if statement *THAT WORKS*?

Tags: javascript

in this little script, the if-else statement is completely missed in the while loop. When I check in the console this `document.getElementById("past-queue-wrapper").lastElementChild.className` pulls the right information from the site but doesn't use the if-else statement to either x2.1 or reset to the base value.

I tried writing

```
document.getElementById("past-queue-wrapper").lastElementChild.className == "past-0  past-tooltip" || "past-1  past-tooltip"){
      document.getElementById("bet-input").value = baseValue;
```

but it still doesn't work. I completely don't know why (new to js).

```
async function startBet(){
  var i = 0;
  var baseValue = 10;
  var betValue = 10;
  var black = "past-0  past-tooltip";
  var red = "past-1  past-tooltip";
  while (i < 1) {

    // CHECK IF LAST WIN WAS GRAY AND IF NOT x2.1
    if (document.getElementById("past-queue-wrapper").lastElementChild.className == black || red){
      document.getElementById("bet-input").value = baseValue;
    }else{
      document.getElementById("bet-input").value = betValue*2.1;
      document.getElementById("bet-input").value = betValue;
    }

    // BET ON GREY
      document.getElementById("bet-btn-2x").click();

    // BET ON RED
      document.getElementById("bet-btn-3x").click();

    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 32000));
}}
```

Comment: You need to write `a == x || a == y`, not `a == (x || y)`

Comment: @Bergi Still not working

Comment: Are you missing an increment for i value, used in while loop ?

Comment: @HemantHalwai Nah I want the loop to be infinite